# NPM packages not available after Node Upgrade

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently upgraded NodeJS from 0.8.X to 0.10.X and now I'm unable to access npm packages I previously had installed. For instance I use jshint frequently and

```
jshint /path/to/file.js
```

just sends back `command not found`. I'm using NVM, so if I switch back via `nvm use 0.8.X` I can then use the modules again.

Assuming I need to re-register the npm's or something, but I'm just curious if there's something more straight-forward I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinstall global packages after upgrading with nvm. There is a separate global  node_modules folder for each version of node that you install with nvm

### Example

0.8 jshint `~/.nvm/v0.8.23/lib/node_modules/jshint`

0.10 jshint `~/.nvm/v0.10.4/lib/node_modules/jshint`